# Manipulating/formatting database output

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've got a database query that outputs the data I need, but I'm not sure how to get it into the format I need (also need to get it into csv format, but need to get the output right first).

```
SELECT `user_id`, `assessment_name`, `question_id`, `question_type_id`, `answer`, `created_at` FROM answer WHERE `assessment_id` = 1
```

The output is like this (although with 30 rows per submission - just put three each here as an example):

```
11  Three Intelligences 31  6   4   7/22/08 11:30
11  Three Intelligences 40  4   4   7/22/08 11:30
11  Three Intelligences 41  6   5   7/22/08 11:30
10  Three Intelligences 31  6   3   7/22/08 14:54
10  Three Intelligences 40  4   4   7/22/08 14:54
10  Three Intelligences 41  6   4   7/22/08 14:54
12  Three Intelligences 31  6   4   7/29/08 10:31
12  Three Intelligences 40  4   4   7/29/08 10:31
12  Three Intelligences 41  6   4   7/29/08 10:31
```

What I need is to reformat this so that it can be used for data analysis, which means getting the data into a single row for each user_id and assessment_name and created_at

```
assessment_name, user_id, answer(for question 31), question_type_id(for question 31), answer(for question 40), question_type_id(for question 40), answer(for question 41), question_type_id(for question 41), created_at
Three Intelligences, 11, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 7/22/08 11:30
Three Intelligences, 10, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 4, 7/22/08 14:54
Three Intelligences, 12, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 7/29/08 10:31
```

Is this possible? If so, I also assume I can do it in php, but I don't know enough to figure out the 'while' loops necessary. It probably doesn't even need to produce a csv file output... if I can just get it properly formatted on the page I can copy/paste for this particular project.

Thanks

--EDIT--
Here's what I've got so far -- this will generate the semi-raw output of the data... I think what I need is just to figure out what loops within loops are required within the 'while' to get the desired output.

```html
<?php
require_once '../connection.php'; 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(localhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
 
 $query_responses = "SELECT `user_id`, `assessment_name`, `question_id`, `question_type_id`, `answer`, `created_at` FROM answer WHERE `assessment_id` = 1";
 $result_responses = $conn->query($query_responses);
 if ($result_responses->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result_responses->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row["created_at"]. ", " .$row["assessment_name"]. ", " .$row["user_id"]. "," .$row["question_id"].  "," .$row["question_type_id"].  "," .$row["answer"].  "<br />";
        
     }
 } else {
     echo "0 results";
 }
 $conn->close();
 
?>
```

Comment: what are you using to retrieve your data from the databse (ex. mysqli, PDO, etc.)?  I'm assuming you are connecting to a db with a php script?

Comment: @Jack Actually, I just started out with a desktop mysql app to figure out which data I need from the database. The is a one-off need, so I figured I would just do a php page to query the db and present the output. (i.e., very basic, not part of a web app or anything)

Comment: Ok, so I did a little reading... I was just going to use mysql and php, but I've found some code to help with doing it as mysqli so that's what I'll go with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it this what you looking for:

```
SELECT
  `user_id`,
  `assessment_name`,
  CONCAT(
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT(`question_type_id`, ', ', `answer`)
   SEPARATOR ', ' ), ', ', `created_at`) AS RESULT
FROM answer 
WHERE `assessment_id` = 1
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `user_id`;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB []> SELECT
    ->   `user_id`,
    ->   `assessment_name`,
    ->   CONCAT(
    ->   GROUP_CONCAT(
    ->     CONCAT(`question_type_id`, ', ', `answer`)
    ->    SEPARATOR ', ' ), ', ', `created_at`) AS RESULT
    -> FROM answer
    -> -- WHERE `assessment_id` = 1
    -> GROUP BY `user_id`
    -> ORDER BY `user_id`;
+---------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| user_id | assessment_name     | RESULT                                      |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|      11 | Three Intelligences | 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 2016-01-01 00:00:00       |
|      12 | Three Intelligences | 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 2016-01-01 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []>
```

Please let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thanks @bernd-buffen ! I was doing some more searching and also got close with this `SELECT created_at, user_id, assessment_name, GROUP_CONCAT(question_id) AS question, GROUP_CONCAT(question_type_id) AS subscale, GROUP_CONCAT(answer) AS response FROM answer WHERE assessment_id = 1 Group By response_uid order by assessment_name;` -- I'm going to give your solution a try. Thanks!